# RichTextBox losing selection/caret position when changing underlying's FlowDocument's text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've implemented "ChangeCase" keyboard shortcut (like Shift+F3 in MS WORD)  for RichTextBox, which changes the text either selected by mouse, or the last word before caret's position. The problem is, it SOMETIMES loses the selection, or moves the caret one word left. 
Once it changes the textcase without this changing of caret position, then it never changes the caret position (propably some WPF's internal caching.), so it can only happen the first time i run this function to a portion of text.

The code used is the solution mentioned in here [WPF Flowdocument "change case" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380112/wpf-flowdocument-change-case-feature) .

One problematic section of code is certainly

```
end = this.CaretPosition;
EditingCommands.MoveLeftByWord.Execute(null, this);
start = this.CaretPosition;
this.CaretPosition = end;
```

However I have no idea why it only occurs sometimes and how to fix this.
I thing it has something to do with the execution speed of this Execute() method and some side effects, because at my WPF app it only happens sometimes, but when hosting this WPF control in Winforms, moving the caret one word left happens all the time (if I hold Shift+F3, the cursor moves word by word to the very beginning of the document)

Other problem can be related with changing text of a TextRange, which is resulting in losing the selection? But again, it doesnt happen all the time and I have no clue how to fix it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with 2 options, ignoring this error or implementing the

```
MoveLeftByWord
```

logic manully without touching the

```
CaretPosition
```